# How to make a required / not required one field depending on value of second field (Drupal in registration form)

Tags: forms

Below is an example of code that makes the first field not required in the form

```
<?php
    function мой_модуль_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
    $form['field_website']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
    }
?>
```

---

```
$form['test']['und'][0]['value']=test;
```

But I need to check the content in the second field after sending the form, and if it coincides with the value of "test", then the first field became not required.

```
if($form['test']['und'][0]['value']=='test'){
    $form['field_website']['und'][0]['#required'] = FALSE;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [Conditional Fields](https://www.drupal.org/project/conditional_fields) module.